# Is the equation $\phi(\pi(\phi^\pi)) = 1$ true? And if so, how?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

$\phi(\pi(\phi^\pi)) = 1$

I saw it on an expired flier for a lecture at the university. I don't know what $\phi$ is, so I tried asking Wolfram Alpha to solve $x \pi x^\pi = 1$ and it gave me a bunch of results with $i$, and I don't know what that is either.

Comment: Could you give us the title of the lecture?  The $ \ \pi \ $ in that equation is likely not the number, but the name of a function or mapping...

Comment: Something about teaching computers to resolve ambiguities. The flier was expired, so we had to throw it away.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks That then makes perfect sense as the computer needs to distinguish between the number $\pi$ and the function $\pi$, and the same goes for $\phi$.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks So I guess the equation does not mean anything by itself but it is an example of an ambiguous equation.

Comment: @Mr.Brooks Not to mention whether these are multiplications (your interpretation) or functions, etc.

Comment: Just FYI, $i$ is the imaginary unit, the principal square root of $-1$. Just in case you want to further explore that sidetrack to your question.

Comment: Square root of a negative number? That sounds way too confusing for me. Maybe in another life.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's a joke based on the use of the [$\phi$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html) (Euler's totient function), the [$\pi$ function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) (the prime counting function), the [constant $\phi$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html) (the golden ratio), and the [constant $\pi$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Pi.html). Note $\phi^\pi\approx 4.5$, so there are two primes less than $\phi^\pi$ (they are $2$ and $3$), so $\pi(\phi^\pi)=2$. There is only one positive integer less than or equal to $2$ which is also relatively prime to $2$ (this number is $1$), so $\phi(2)=1$. Hence we have

$$\phi(\pi(\phi^\pi))=\phi(2)=1$$

Comment: Thanks!  I thought someone else would be better able to interpret it than I would; I was thinking some sort of algebraic mapping was being referred to (rather than something from number theory)...

Comment: Brilliant! I only have one thing to add, since the asker mentioned Wolfram|Alpha: I have a feeling that one day soon, Wolfram Mathematica will be able to instinctively resolve the symbolic ambiguities in that equation and understand it internally as "EulerPhi[PrimePi[GoldenRatio^Pi]]".